# How to install YouCompleteMe with Clang completer offline?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-vundle, plugin-clang-complete

I have installed YouCompleteMe with Clang completer in OS X 10.10.4, and in my new OS X 10.11.4 I want to reinstall it.

The previous installation process downloaded about 140MB at very low speed. I have used the main [tutorial](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/README.md#mac-os-x) to install with these commands (after installing the bundle with [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)):

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer
```

How can I manually download the additional file and install it offline?

Comment: What is this "Clang Completer" you speak of? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @PeterMortensen "Clang Completer" a libclang-based completer that provides semantic completion for C-family languages in YCM ([reference](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd#how-ycmd-works)). There is an optional `--clang-completer` argument in [build.py].(https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/build.py#L245-L246)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did the following to install (Although I could copy the whole `~/.vim` directory to the new place instead of steps 3-6):

1. Install vim 7.4:

   ```
   brew install vim
   ```

   Note: If you are using mac operating system, make sure you create an alias in your bash_profile pointing to macvim i.e. `which mvim`
2. Install [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)
3. Add `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` to `~/.vimrc` and run `:PluginInstall` in vim.
4. Download **clang+llvm-*version*-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz** from `Pre-Built Binaries` section of [LLVM Download Page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) manually (now it is the latest version).
5. Make the download directory:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/clang_archives
   ```
6. Put the downloaded file in that directory.

   ```
   mv  clang+llvm-*-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/clang_archives
   ```
7. Compile YouCompleteMe:

   ```
   cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
   ./install.py --clang-completer
   ```

Comment: In this solution I used Vundle, so there is no need to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` because Vundle do [this](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/README.md#full-installation-guide) while running `:PluginInstall`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

Put this at the top of your .vimrc to use Vundle.

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Run following to install:

```
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe
git submodule update --init --recursive
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

Comment: You should be able to see if YCM plugin is installed by starting vim and writing :PluginInstall

Comment: Does this solution meet the **offline** requirement that is the main requirement in the question? Your post is the answer of "How to install Vundle and YouCompleteMe online?"

Comment: The only online part is where you fetch the thing you want to install - this could be done at an earlier stage - I do not see how you can install something you do not have - all other answers expect first line - I however have just expressed how to first get the package - you could leave it out

Comment: also are you saying that  
brew install vim   
is an offline action ??